# The name BoolToColorConverter does not exist in the namespace “clr-namespace:TME.Viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, ivalueconverter

Im using MVVM light and I have a problem to implement an IValueConverter.

The error-message is:

**"The name BoolToColorConverter does not exist in the namespace “clr-namespace:TME.Viewmodel"**

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:ignore="http://www.ignore.com"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" xmlns:Custom="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
        x:Class="TME.MainWindow"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:TME.Design"

        mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
        Height="367"
        Width="681"
        Title="MVVM Light Application" Background="Black" Loaded="Window_Loaded"
        >

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            **<l:BoolToColorConverter></l:BoolToColorConverter>**
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Skins/MainSkin.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
         </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
```

And my other class looks like this.

```
namespace TME.Design
{
public class BoolToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
        }

        return System.Convert.ToBoolean(value) ?
            new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)
          : new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Dont understand why it doesnt find my booltocolorconverter although the xaml-editor in Visual studio gives the opportunity to choose it via intelisense.

Take care

Jurgen

Comment: Are you able to build your whole project...check for your references in xaml

Comment: Clean & rebuild maybe. Also move converter right below window.resources, out of resource dictionary?

Comment: @user2440589 I'm guessing it cannot compile everything because you forgot to add `x:Key` like `<l:BoolToColorConverter x:Key="BoolToColorConverter"/>`: _All objects added to an IDictionary must have a Key attribute or some other type of key associated with them_. Add it and then it should be able to compile it and then find it

Comment: *"The name BoolToColorConverter does not exist in the namespace “clr-namespace:TME.Viewmodel"* looks down... ***namespace TME.Design*** come on, man.  What's really going on here?  Your question doesn't make sense.